# SQL select at least X rows that are in a given time

Tags: sql, select

i am looking for an SQL query, that selects exactly rows ordered by date from a table. for this there is a column that contains a timestamp.

and here comes the tricky part:
it should not select rows that are older than a certain time, but it should still select at least X rows. 
so if in the given time there are not more than X rows, it should move the time back until it has at least X rows.

thanks!

Comment: it uses the SQL:1999 standard

Comment: Limiting rowsets is very different between databases, so we'll really need the software name (mysql, oracle, sqlserver, etc)

Comment: it is the free version of IBM DB2

Comment: The SQL Server timestamp data type has nothing to do with times or dates. SQL Server timestamps are binary numbers that indicate the relative sequence in which data modifications took place in a database. The timestamp data type was originally implemented to support the SQL Server recovery algorithms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 

    (SELECT TOP 100 *
    FROM MyTable
    ORDER BY dateColumn DESC) A

UNION

    (SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE dateColumn > '20090101')
```

Comment: +1 Great find!  A side effect of this is that it removes duplicate rows

Comment: What if you want the duplicate original duplicate row?
Anyway still great answer

Comment: The UNION (as opposed to the UNION ALL) will remove duplicate rows, even if they both originate from one side of the query

Comment: If UNION removes duplicate rows, even if from the same side of the query as @Andomar says, then why is DISTINCT needed?

Comment: @Andy: the `distinct` is not required here, since the `union` already removes duplicate rows

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve this by sorting by two columns. The sort column would be an expression that says whether the row is in the specified date range. The second sort column would be the date itself

something like

```
select top x *
from the_table
order by 
    case when the_table.the_date between '1-jan-2009' and '31-jan-2009' then 0 else 1 end,
    the_table.the_date desc
```

Comment: As I understand the question, he doesn't want to limit the maximum number of rows returned, so this wouldn't be ideal.